How should/do dictionaries display and relate orthographic and pronunciation variants of an underlying concept?
In English we have "color" and "colour", which is the same underlying concept, but just different spellings. So it would be wrong (IMO) for a database-driven electronic dictionary to have 2 entries (color and colour), with the same set of definitions, but the definitions are duplicated and not stored as the same underlying object.
Instead, I might create an intermediate object, "concepts" (DB table), which has definitions, and the "strings" table is the spelling. Perhaps something like this:
concepts
id  token
1   COLOR

definitions
id  concept   text
1   COLOR     A tone that you see.
2   COLOR     Part of the visible light spectrum (I dunno).

strings
id  text      concept
1   color     COLOR
2   colour    COLOR

Then you can search by color or colour, and it will return the same underlying data.
The only extreme example I can think of that I have encountered is the ORACC Cuneiform glosses, which have, for each "entry", a set of "forms", which are the various ways it is written (which is also pronounced differently I think, which is more intense than my English example), and a set of "norms", which are standardized "forms" I guess.
So that example (Cuneiform/Sumerian/Akkadian/etc.), has not only orthographic differences, but large pronunciation differences, so say 10 of these variants can map to one and the same underlying concept. I think the Ancient Egyptian dictionary data I've seen might be similar to this.
Not sure if my DB model would conceptually make things easier to manage. Not sure how complex it can get.
Like you wouldn't say that "dog" and "canine" are the same exact thing, they are different concepts. But "color" and "colour" are the same. But how many languages have this "problem"? Which languages have more "variants" than others?
A related example is traditional vs. simplified Chinese. But I would call this an transcription variant rather than a spelling variant. Transcription variants are things like Pinyin, to Chinese characters, or IAST to Devanagari, romanization to native, etc.. They are different in my head than the spelling variants. (Or in the case of Cuneiform, the pronunciation variants). Or maybe they're the same, not sure.
Another related example is vowel diacritics in Hebrew and Arabic (with/without). I would consider these transcription variants, not spelling/pronunciation variants though, so these are similar to simplified/traditional Chinese.
Basically what I'm trying to get at is, it seems there are underlying hidden things called "concepts", which are mapped to one or more "forms" (strings or pronunciations). So how does/should a dictionary display and relate these?

This is very standard for languages that use cuneiform, since spelling was never really standardized. It came down to the whim of the individual scribe. For example, here's a Hittite verb from Huehnergard:


lƗ-i / l- (IIa1α > Ic2) ‘to loosen, to release, to untie, to relieve, to remove (ailments)’ (Sum. DU8): 1sg.pres.act. la-a-mi (NH), 2sg.pres.act. la-a-ši (NH), 3sg.pres.act. la-a-i (OH or MH/MS), la-a-iz-zi (MH/MS), la-a-i-iz-zi (MH/MS), 1pl.pres.act. la-a-u-e-ni (NH), 3pl.pres.act. la-an-zi (OS), la-a-an-zi (NH), 1sg.pret.act. la-a-nu-un (OH/NS), 2sg.pret.act. la-i-iš (NH), 3sg.pret.act. la-a-it (NH), 1pl.pret.act. la-a-u-en (MH/NS), la-a-u-e-en (NH), 3pl.pret.act. la-a-er (OH/NS), la-a-e-er, 2sg.imp.act. la-a (OH/MS), la-a-a (MH/MS), la-a-i (OH/NS), 3sg.imp.act. la-a-ú (OH or MH/MS), la-a-ad-du (NH), 2pl.imp.act. la-a-at-te-en (MH/MS), la-a-at-tén (NH), 3pl.imp.act. la-a-an-du (Bo 6405 obv. 6 (undat.)); 3sg.pres.midd. la-a-it-ta-ri (NH), la-it-ta-ri (NH), 3sg.pret.midd. la-a-at-ta-at, la-at-ta-at (NH), 3sg.imp.midd. la-a-at-ta-ru (NH); part. la-a-an-t- (MH/MS); verb.noun la-a-u-wa-ar (NS), gen.sg. la-a-u-wa-aš; inf.I la-u-an-zi (MH/MS); impf. la-a-iš-ke/a- (MH/MS)

This lists all the attested forms of the verb, and all the attested spellings for each form. So for example the third singular present active can be either lāi or lāizzi, and the latter can be spelled either la-a-iz-zi or la-a-i-iz-zi.
Most dictionaries for living languages don't try to list all attested forms, because there are just too many attestations! But they should still list major spelling variations.
